# Ruby on Rails View Does Not Render (Loads Blank)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rss

I am working on implementing an RSS feed in Ruby on Rails to syndicate real estate listings (first with Zillow, then others). Currently I am struggling hard to get the views to load.

I've attempted to search SO to see if another question was close or answer worked and come up blank. As such I apologize if this is redundant but it is unintentional.

Ruby on Rails Version: 7.0.4

Route:

```
require 'sidekiq/web'
require 'sidekiq/cron/web'
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  if ENV['ENABLE_INTERNAL_ROUTES'] || Rails.env.development?
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
    mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  end

  mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql" if ENV['APP_ENV'] != 'production'
  post "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute"
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"

  mount Rswag::Ui::Engine => '/api-docs'
  mount Rswag::Api::Engine => '/api-docs'

  get '/feeds/zillow', to: 'feeds#zillow'
end
```

Controllers:
Feeds Controller `app/controllers/feeds_controller.rb`

```
class FeedsController < ApplicationController
  def zillow
    @listings = Listing.where(syndication_type: 'SYNDICATION_ON')
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render "feeds/zillow" }
      format.rss { render layout: false }
    end
  end
end
```

ApplicationController `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
end
```

Views:
zillow.html.erb `app/views/feeds/zillow.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Temporary for checking</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Do we even exist?</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

zillow.rss.builder `app/views/feeds/zillow.rss.builder`

```
# app/views/posts/index.xml.builder
xml.instruct! :xml, version: "1.0"
xml.rss version: "2.0" do
  xml.channel do
    xml.title "RSS Rails"
    xml.description "Some random description. We will expand later"
  end
end
```

Request:
`curl -i http://localhost:3000/feeds/zillow.rss`

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: _session_id=jONgfsG5hiFzPuehEmFthv9vl8l1YATsyC912Ijjr7xZxO8YqQugUfxQt2S%2Bgi1W5s%2BBRxn4YbjxO9OSODjoxrCe7lf9lYUlVK7fnWaPAiBq1Wl49JJtarxeij8S809cUQ%2By4lXDEQKoeAn7s1ru3VK2SF%2FcB5PmgkO%2BLSfLfnfxd3s%3D--uQrBRqJR724ukUkt--xOyV9DgdzMPUplOFYye1FA%3D%3D; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
ETag: W/"36a9e7f1c95b82ffb99743e0c5c4ce95"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: cc95c787-c0fb-42ab-9f80-2ab2fe57182a
X-Runtime: 0.014212
Server-Timing: start_processing.action_controller;dur=0.01, process_action.action_controller;dur=0.56
Vary: Origin
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

 %
```

Searching has informed me that the single `%` returned signifies an end of the response. Of note is this downloads a file that is completely empty rather than serving up a blank page.

If I remove, from the FeedsController, the directive causing `.rss` requests to not render the layout I get the following:

Request:
`curl -i http://localhost:3000/feeds/zillow.rss`

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Set-Cookie: _session_id=MjmWc%2BJ%2FxvWdCymjPQxsJdNgZXkeyGs3ziJTk5lsiLTpqrLNzvYBIKDwYTtjDIBoNbBT%2FN05ukgfsns05AC9rfnafg2A%2BpF9UqFZlR7xUZNtN2xn%2BxdcpXBz7nJMRR2G6S7oH%2FfZcwEnImq5hM50iPOwugvewRjrh78no5V9Z1gsUWg%3D--XH8SskCjhWEW3pRV--bxxYHh8%2FJQeBMCm9VcmrNw%3D%3D; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: 84bae277-3507-48b4-b61f-51363058f6e6
X-Runtime: 0.466036
Server-Timing: sql.active_record;dur=8.88, start_processing.action_controller;dur=0.01, process_action.action_controller;dur=18.36
Vary: Origin
```

Request:

`curl -i http://localhost:3000/feeds/zillow`

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Set-Cookie: _session_id=YDL5FHg4A4jbIXfqTz6kw6FSyVOLfkDd9l7r6kdMMicqtZJRW4ggkULeTu5Nv6RJpNH36TLxIHdTp6%2BxQV6PKGLTR30IyamNzjMUij2IJKhBi%2B8aMsk6fzR4HNpjmQ%2Fh0pIVJvtX7JD25ROWDPbp4Ay6Y22BDSSLpvLApMWvFlTxeOQ%3D--nVZ3vQfPxCDfn%2BO2--yjA0VUMoEvACtvzROGzQ9Q%3D%3D; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: 036d1ad5-1b7c-4d45-929b-9d676eb02092
X-Runtime: 0.012600
Server-Timing: start_processing.action_controller;dur=0.01, process_action.action_controller;dur=0.52
Vary: Origin
```

I have confirmed that there is local data seeded that is being returned. I'm clearly missing something but I don't know what.

Thanks in advance for whatever help is offered!

Comment: Does `format.rss { render :zillow, layout: false }` fix the problem? I'm not 100% sure but I suspect that when you call `render` explicitly without any options telling it what to render it doesn't behave like implicit rendering.

Comment: Hey @max, thanks for responding! Making this refactor made no noticeable change in the response

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive the same thing just by setting the layout options on the controller level and letting implicit rendering do the heavy lifting:

```
class FeedsController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Layouts
  layout false, only: [:rss]
  
  def zillow
    @listings = Listing.where(syndication_type: 'SYNDICATION_ON')
    respond_to :html, :rss
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey @max, thanks once more for the feedback! Making this refactor raises the following exception at line 2:

`#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'layout' for FeedsController:Class>`

Comment: @CoreyCramer ah, the method must be provided by one of the modules that isn't included in ActionController::API. It would probally be easier to just make your controller inherit from `ActionController::Base`.

Comment: The missing module is [ActionView::Layouts](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Layouts.html).

Comment: Making the change to where the controller inherits from did it. Thank you once more, Max!

Comment: Moreover applying the edited solution works while still inheriting from API. Marking this as the correct answer for whomever comes next!

Comment: @CoreyCramer click the checkmark to indicate that this is THE answer to your question.